# ionic2 remove blue line color input md

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, material-design

How can I remove the default line below the text input md.

I already tried all of these below, but the "default" styling still keeps this line.

[image]

```
$text-input-md-highlight-color: "transparent";
$text-input-md-highlight-color-invalid : "transparent";
$text-input-md-highlight-color-valid : "transparent";
$text-input-md-background-color : "transparent";
$text-input-md-show-focus-highlight : "transparent";
$text-input-md-show-invalid-highlight: "transparent";
$text-input-md-show-valid-highlight : "transparent";
$text-input-md-show-success-highlight:      false;
$text-input-md-show-error-highlight:        false;
// Input highlight - normal
$text-input-md-highlight-color:             "transparent";

// Input highlight - valid
$text-input-md-hightlight-color-valid:      "transparent";

// Input highlight - invalid
$text-input-md-hightlight-color-invalid:    "transparent";
```

Comment: try inspecting that element on chrome dev tools, maybe it seems like .item-md .item-inner or something like that

Comment: That was my occupation this morning ;) - No luck with that, but fixed now

Comment: Is there any solution for ionic 3?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

try using the following code:

```
.item-md.item-input.input-has-focus .item-inner {
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.list-md .item-input.input-has-focus:last-child {
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.list-md .item-input.input-has-focus:last-child .item-inner {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.item-md.item-input.ng-valid.input-has-value:not(.input-has-focus) .item-inner {
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.list-md .item-input.ng-valid.input-has-value:not(.input-has-focus):last-child {
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.list-md .item-input.ng-valid.input-has-value:not(.input-has-focus):last-child .item-inner {
  box-shadow: none;
}

.item-md.item-input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(.input-has-focus) .item-inner {
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.list-md .item-input.ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(.input-has-focus):last-child {
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

it'll remove all validation lines (red/green/blue).

### EDIT

There's a better way for doing this using theming.

Go to your `theme.scss` file inside `src/theme` and use this code

```
$text-input-md-highlight-color-invalid: transparent;
$text-input-md-highlight-color-valid: transparent;
$text-input-md-show-invalid-highlight: transparent;
$text-input-md-highlight-color: transparent;
$text-input-md-show-valid-highlight: transparent;
```

Comment: Thanks! I adapted it for non focus state and it works!

.item-md.item-input .item-inner {
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.list-md .item-input:last-child {
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

Comment: Works great - I guess you could probably even omit the upper code and just use variables.scss for this - much better solution

Comment: Is there any solution for ionic3 ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is another version, without `!imporant` keyword:

```
 ion-content {
    %no-input-border {
      border-bottom-color: transparent;
      box-shadow: none;
    }

    ion-item {
      &.item-input {
        &.item-md {
          &.input-has-focus {
            .item-inner {
              @extend %no-input-border;
            }
          }
        }

        &.ng-invalid {
          &.item-md {
            &.ng-touched:not(.input-has-focus):not(.item-input-has-focus) {
              .item-inner {
                @extend %no-input-border;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        &.ng-valid {
          &.item-md {
            &.input-has-value:not(.input-has-focus):not(.item-input-has-focus) {
              .item-inner {
                @extend %no-input-border;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous version of ionic have a attribute **no-lines**
Which is now depricated

**So for the latest version you should use the property** ---> 
**lines="none"**

Example :

```
 <ion-item class="textArea" lines="none">
    <ion-textarea autoGrow="true" placeholder="Enter more information here..."></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
```

This will remove the blue line.
Hope this will help you or somebody else!